# Auto Scroll listboxitems placed inside a listbox

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

HI , i want to auto scroll the listboxitems placed inside a listbox., it has nothing to do related with the scrollbar. Somewhat like what marquee does..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

It seems possible to loop through each item and call this: [ScrollIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview(v=VS.95).aspx)